# Scala how can I uppercase first character and lowercase others

Tags: scala

I basically have a form that takes user input and I match it in the database. I want the first character uppercase and characters with spaces and all others lowercase. Right now I have this

```
  location= location.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
```

The code above does this: if a user types **'new york**' it gets converted to **'New York'**, however if a user types **NeW YoRk** I still want it converted to the form **'New York'**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just convert it all to lowercase first:

```
_.toLowerCase.capitalize
```